# ERROR at //skia/BUILD.gn while building Chromedriver locally

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am trying to build ChromeDriver ([114.0.5735.90](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/bb5258320e0aca193f0f9c0dcf2987b2a3c8f551)) locally on a windows machine and facing the error as :

```
ERROR at //skia/BUILD.gn:554:16: Undefined identifier
    sources += skia_gpu_private
               ^---------------
See //BUILD.gn:103:7: which caused the file to be included.
      "//skia:skia_unittests",
      ^----------------------
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
ninja: Entering directory `outDefault'
[0/1] Regenerating ninja files
FAILED: build.ninja.stamp
../buildtools/win/gn.exe --root=./.. -q --regeneration gen .
```

What I have tried with no avail:

- gclient sync
- Building the latest version

Reference screenshot:
[image: Here is the screenshot for reference:]

Comment: did you run `gclient sync` before starting the compilation process?

Comment: Yes @Asesh , ran "gclient sync" before starting the compilation process but same result.

Comment: Looks like you are using Windows. Can you try to do the same thing from `Visual Studio Command Prompt` instead of Git bash? I remember facing a similar problem before...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer  @Asesh. I tried the same commands from VS Command Prompt and was facing "build.ninja is not found". So I did "git reset --hard HEAD" on the repo. Followed it by "git clean -ffd". Ran "gclient sync -f". And then gave up on VS Command Prompt. Then I switched back to Git Bash. Ran "gclient sync -D". After this made my changes in Visual studio and ran "autoninja -C out\Default chromedriver" in Git bash. The build gods were happy, and I was able to build Chromedriver locally. 
Thanks for your pointer and hopefully someone finds this helpful in the future. 